# Error #2084-The AMF Encoding of the arguments cannot exceed 40K

Tags: flex3, flex4, localconnection

In my application I am using `localConnection` object for communication b/w Flex 3 and Flex 4 swfs. But when the size of the arguments (`ArrayCollection`) exceeds certain limit , I am getting following exception:-

> `Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.LocalConnection was unable to invoke callback readyToUpdate. error=ArgumentError: Error #2084: The AMF encoding of the arguments cannot exceed 40K.`

Any inputs on same will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a related post here.  The last thing mentioned was to check to make sure your array doesn't have a length of 0.  Not sure how this translates into exceeding 40K but something to look at.  Try to figure out how much data you are trying to send if there is data in the array...
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/243519

Answer (score 0):

old question, but I just solved this by

```
content.position=0;
```